# Text attribute to drop down

Tags: magento2, attributes, dropdown-attribute

I am running magento 2 and would like to convert my text attribute to a dropdown menu. I am comfortable to mysql and php but i do not really understand that database structure.

Is it possible to convert text attributes to drop down lists if so can you give me some pointers

I have seen [this](https://gist.github.com/mechanicalgux/92aa186aaf65965e67af)
but this is for `Magento 1.9`